# JQueryUI .selectable events

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I got a small problem in JQuery .selectable function

what I wanna do is bind some events to each tabs.

I can handle a click event of each tabs

but the problem is when I select two or more tabs,

I can't figure out how I handle it.

for example, if I click(and also just select by dragging) one tab,

some sorting function must be works and

also each different defined function must be works in dragging multiple selections.

Ofcourse, I can use some flag cheat to solve this

but that is not what I really want.

does anyone have some effective solutions?

```
   $("#selectable2").selectable(
    {
        selected: function()
        {
           $(".arcplan").on("selectableselected", function()
           {
               $(".big-tile").hide(200);
           }) 

        }
    });


 <div class="menu">
    <div class="inner">
        <ol id="selectable2">
           <li class="alltype2">all</li>
           <li class="arcplan">Arcplan</li>
           <li class="msbi">MSBI</li></li>
           <li class="excel">Excel</li>
           <li class="etc">etc</li>
        </ol>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: $("#selectable").selectable(); is just all I have done.

Comment: looks like a poem... :) and no code/fiddle...:(

Comment: I just uploaded some codes. I meant I need some function work depend on each list's status (click, drag both selection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$("#selectable2").selectable({
  selected : function(event, ui) {
    if($(ui.selected).hasClass('arcplan')){
      $(".big-tile").hide(200);
    }
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://plnkr.co/edit/NMdTxlpLfR3o8P36YUQo?p=preview) - when you click on `Arcplan` the `big-tile` element is hidden and if you select anything else it is displayed back.

Comment: works perfect and exactly what I want. I never thought to try to use hasclass for filtering. Forgive this little newbie. thx Arun!

Answer (score 0):

From the docs (http://api.jqueryui.com/selectable/#event-selected):

```
$('#selectable2').selectable();
$('#selectable2').on('selectableselected', function(event, ui){
  doSomethingWithTheSelected(event.target);
});
```

Comment: I just changed some codes based on following example you gave but still doesn't work. please give me some hints..

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: It looks like you have a few errors in your code. You're using a class selector instead of an id and you're registering the selectableselected event listener to a random element.

Comment: I copied wrong code from editor I changed class selector to id but still doesn't work. How do I register the selectableselected event listener to a specific element? For example, when I want to make some event binding when I drag, click(select motion) a li class= excel, How Can I use the selectableselected event listner properly?